# Speeding slicing of big numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, slice, pytables

I have a big array ( 1000x500000x6 ) that is stored in a pyTables file. I am doing some calculations on it that are fairly optimized in terms of speed, but what is taking the most time is the slicing of the array.

At the beginning of the script, I need to get a subset of the rows : reduced_data = data[row_indices, :, :] and then, for this reduced dataset, I need to access:

- columns one by one: reduced_data[:,clm_indice,:]
- a subset of the columns: reduced_data[:,clm_indices,:]

Getting these arrays takes forever. Is there any way to speed that up ? storing the data differently for example ?

Comment: I think you should try to get them by rows, since this is (I believe) the way they are ordered in the file. It can make a lot of difference in such a large table.

Comment: Is the PyTables data stored in a table or array?

Comment: @dtlussier the data is stored in a compressed Carray.

Comment: @Lior I thought about that, but I also access the data by rows so it would move the problem from the middle of my script to the beginning.... however, as there are so many more columns that rows, maybe it would speed things up a little to transpose the data.

Comment: For arrays - I think @pv. answer below is a good start.  Would it be possible to store as a table? This would allow for an easier way to access columns, or subsets of rows in a way which is similar to database querying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try choosing the `chunkshape` of your array wisely, see: http://pytables.github.com/usersguide/libref.html#tables.File.createCArray
This option controls in which order the data is physically stored in the file, so it might help to speed up access.

With some luck, for your data access pattern, something like `chunkshape=(1000, 1, 6)` might work.

Comment: I haven't tested that yet but I am marking it as the best answer as it pointed me to an interesting option I hadn't seen by myself. Thanks !